# Are these matrices in row echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As I'm learning linear algebra, this questions confuses me so much.

> which of the following matrices are in row echelon form? For each matrix not in row echelon form, explain why it is not

$$ a) 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    1 & -1 & 4 \\
    0 & 2 & -7 \\
    0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

$$ b) 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    1 & 4 & -4 & -5 \\
    0 & 0 & 4 & -8 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

$$ c) 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    1 & -2 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & -8 & -3 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

The reason why i'm getting super confused is because all these 3 matrices can be transformed into row echelon form. For instance if you divide row 2 in matrix $a$ and divide 3, that gets you row echelon form. And for $c$) if you change row 2, 3 then you get row echelon form. However, this question specifically asked if these 3 matrices are in row echelon form. So I don't know if transforming is allowed. What do you guys think about this question?

Because i know in order to be row echelon form implies that:

1. The leading (first) entry in each row must be 1
2. The leading entry on each subsequent row must be on a new column to the right
3. All rows where all entries are zero are below rows where NOT all entries are zero

Comment: (a) and (b) are. (c) is not. Generally, you will be asked to identify them just by looking at them.

Comment: @poyea how can you tell?

Comment: Stick with definitions! Note that row echelon form doesn't need to be **reduced**. It seems that you mixed REF and RREF up.

Comment: @poyea but by the definition, the leading entry of each row of a matrix has to be 1. but for a) clearly its not

Comment: See [REF on WiKi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).

Comment: The definitions that I had learned, that I understand to be the standard definition, as well as the definitions that I subsequently *taught* is that for a (*not necessarily reduced*) row echelon form matrix leading entries do not need to be specifically $1$'s.  The requirement that they are strictly $1$'s is strictly only included in the definition of *reduced* row echelon forms.  It is possible that your teacher and/or your book are including this in the definition of row echelon forms that you are being taught.  If that is so, then none of them are in row echelon form.

Comment: If you choose not to require that the pivot entries must be ones, i.e. that you allow pivot entries to be any nonzero number, then as mentioned (a) and (b) are both in REF (*though not in RREF*) and (c) is not in REF or RREF.

Comment: As for "are you allowed to transform these"  The question asks if the matrices are *currently* in REF.  It should be a well known property to you that every matrix *can be transformed* into REF via elementary row operations, but those transformed matrices *are not equal to* the original matrices in many cases.  As for "how can you tell?" as said earlier, look at the specific definition.  A handwavy explanation is that you can see a "staircase pattern" if you color in all zeroes that are on the left or immediately to the right of another colored in zero.  If not REF, then its more jigsaw shaped

Comment: In the first two examples, the zeroes do indeed follow such a staircase pattern:  $\begin{pmatrix}&&\\0&&\\0&0&\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}&&\\0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.  The third matrix does not: $\begin{pmatrix}&&\\0&0\\0&\end{pmatrix}$.  The "stairs" in these patterns should go from the lower steps in the bottom right to the higher steps in the top left.  Steps can be long and steps can be high, they don't need to go up and over one at a time.  You just don't want any of the zeroes to be "floating in midair."  Again, this is all formalized in a full precise definition.

Comment: @krishna Dividing a row by a number is an acceptable row operation.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that if a matrix is not in row echelon form, then it is not in row echelon form (even if it can be transformed to row echelon form!)

Definitions of REF can vary (see the Wikipedia one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form), so by your definition none of these matrices are in REF, since none of them have leading entries all equal to 1.

However, if this condition on the leading entries were relaxed (that is, leading entries do not have to be equal to 1), then (a) and (b) are in REF, and (c) is not (because it violates condition 2...can you see why?).

Hope this helps! :)